# Notepad ++ regex expression to put quotes around the contents of square brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large number of ACCESS, SQL expressions with numeric column names. I'm editing with Notepad++
I want to put quotes around those particular names, and not any other names inside square brackets.

```
[243_type_conversion]
```

becomes this

```
["243_type_conversion"]
```

I've tried this:

```
find what:    (\[)([0-9])(.*)(\])
replace with: \1"\2\3"\4
```

but in this example:

```
 SELECT HAZARD.[LOAN_NO],HAZARD.[FIRST_PRIN_BAL],HAZARD.[352_Ins_Co_Code] from HAZARD where (((HAZARD.[352_Ins_Co_Code]) = [PAYEE_CODE] ));
```

I get this:

```
 SELECT HAZARD.[LOAN_NO],HAZARD.[FIRST_PRIN_BAL],HAZARD.["352_Ins_Co_Code] from HAZARD where (((HAZARD.[352_Ins_Co_Code"]) = [PAYEE_CODE] ));
```

When I need this:

```
 SELECT HAZARD.[LOAN_NO],HAZARD.[FIRST_PRIN_BAL],HAZARD.["352_Ins_Co_Code"] from HAZARD where (((HAZARD.["352_Ins_Co_Code"]) = [PAYEE_CODE] ));
```

Any ideas would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put some limits on matching domain. Remove greedy dot `.*` and put `[^\]]*`:

```
\[(\d[^\]]*)\]
```

and replace with `["\1"]`

Answer (score 2):

Capture the whole thing then put it back

```
Search: \[(\d+\w+)\]
Replace: ["$1"]
```